# Tezos Stackexchange Logo

Tags: discussion, design

I notized that compared to Ethereum Stackexchange - Tezos has not its logo, just XTZ.
See here:

[image]

I am suggesting to update the current "logo" and favicon to the actual Tezos logo.
No new design etc, lets just use the existing Tezos logo like on tezos dot com. Who is in charge of that and can do this?

I saw a similar discussion about logos/theme etc on the [ethereum meta](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/706/site-design-and-logo-draft) - thats why I figured it will be good to post here.
What do you think?

Comment: No, because Tezos Stackexchange is out of beta. So now it can have its own logo.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: No problem, if you know the process how to change the logo now please feel free to tell.

Comment: I like this idea. We may need some designs that we can put to a broader community vote.

Comment: Great, what would be the process. A new post on Tezos Meta to call for designs and share it in the artist community? Or pick some Tezos logo designs and put it up for a vote? Happy to help just dont know the process.

Comment: I just contacted a member of our Community Management Team and asked for guidance on this matter. Will provide more details as soon as I get it. Thanks for getting the ball rolling @Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a great idea.

However in terms of process we will need to wait for the SE design team to work through their backlog of sites awaiting logo/site designs. I'm guessing it make take a while.

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378888/with-new-designs-planned-for-some-sites-are-there-plans-to-tackle-the-backlog/) for more details.

Comment: Ok thank you. So the only thing we can do now is to wait, do I understand that correctly? Once the SE team worked through their backlog they will approach us/the mods of Tezos Stackexchange?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.